# HTML <Option> is not returning value when user select it

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have a SQL query that should fill a listview on HTML and this is working fine. The problem is when user selects the value on the listbox, the variable is null and the SQL statement to INSERT is missing the value of this variable resulting on an Error.

Below is the code when I get the values to prepare my SQL statement, all variable is working and receiving the value user is inputing except $clcargo because it is the unique listview I have in the form

```
$clregistro = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST['clregistro']);
$clnome = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST['clnome']);
$clsobrenome = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST['clsobrenome']);
$cldtnasc = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST['cldtnasc']);
$clrg = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST['clrg']);
$clcpf = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST['clcpf']);
$clcnh = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST['clcnh']);
$clcidade = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST['clcidade']);
$clestado = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST['clestado']);
$clcep = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST['clcep']);
$clrua = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST['clrua']);
$clnum = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST['clnum']);
$clbairro = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST['clbairro']);
$cltel = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST['cltel']);
$clcel = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST['clcel']);
$clemail = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST['clemail']);
$clsex = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST['clsex']);
$clcargo = (isset($_POST['clcargo'])?$_POST['clcargo'] : null); 
$ciduser = $_SESSION['id_users'];

$sql = "INSERT INTO funcionarios (registro, nome, sobrenome, nascimento, rg, cpf, cnh, cidade, estado, cep, rua, numero, bairro, telefone, cel, email, sexo, id_cargo, ativo, id_user)
VALUES ('$clregistro','$clnome','$clsobrenome','$cldtnasc','$clrg','$clcpf','$clcnh','$clcidade','$clestado','$clcep','$clrua','$clnum','$clbairro','$cltel','$clcel','$clemail','$clsex', '$clcargo', 1, $ciduser)";
if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE)
```

When I try to register a member, the SQL return this due the null value from $clcargo:

```
Error: INSERT INTO funcionarios (registro, nome, sobrenome, nascimento, rg, cpf, cnh, cidade, estado, cep, rua, numero, bairro, telefone, cel, email, sexo, id_cargo, ativo, id_user) VALUES ('1212','Diego Artur','Ferreira Campos','1988-09-04','41349658','35237976832','81349662','Campinas','SP','13054661','Rua Cecília Sigrist','20','Dic VI (Conjunto Habitacional Santo Dias Silva)','19 3266-8957','19 98114-1090','diegoart.fc@gmail.com','Masculino', '', 1, 1)
Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`u682912079_bd`.`funcionarios`, CONSTRAINT `id_cargo_func` FOREIGN KEY (`id_cargo`) REFERENCES `cargo` (`id_cargo`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
```

This is the code to load information in the list view

```
<form method="post">

 <?php

    $conn = new mysqli($servername, $serverlogin, $password, $dbname);
    $query = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT id_cargo, descricao FROM cargo");

?>
<div class="form-group row">
    <div class="col-md-6">

    <label for="exampleFormControlInput1">Cargo / Função</label>

    <select class="custom-select" id="inputGroupSelect01">
        <option>Selecione o cargo...</option>
    <?php while($proc = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) { ?>
    <option name="clcargo" value="<?php echo $proc['id_cargo'] ?>"><?php echo $proc['descricao'] ?></option>
    <?php } ?>
  </select>
    </div>

</div>
<hr>

<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-user btn-block" name="reg_f">Cadastrar</button>
```

What I expect is the variable $clcargo being fulfilled with the user's choice.

Comment: Hi, i guess u misunderstood the select tag. there's no `name` attribute for `<option>` tag. Give `<select name='some_name_here'>`

Comment: Thank you Dharman, I am new on programming, I am going to read more about it and apply on my project.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<select name="clcargo" class="custom-select" id="inputGroupSelect01">
    <option>Selecione o cargo...</option>
<?php while($proc = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) { ?>
<option value="<?php echo $proc['id_cargo'] ?>"><?php echo $proc['descricao'] ?></option>
<?php } ?>
```

The name field must be in `<select>` not in `<option>`

Comment: Thank you so much, I did what you suggested and it is working now. 
Have a nice day brother!

Answer (score 1):

For this to work properly, you must add a `name` attribute to the `<select>` and a `value` attribute to each `<option>`.

Comment: And do *not* put a name in the option tag, as I did to start with!